# Fee amount is incorrect

Tags: commerce, rules

I have created a fee type. I set up a rule according to the steps on the module's front page. I have it set to add $5.50 to the order. However, it is only adding $0.06 to the order instead.

Here is my rule (it's disabled since it isn't currently working):

```
{ "rules_handling_fee" : {
"LABEL" : "Handling fee",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"ACTIVE" : false,
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_physical", "commerce_fees" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_fees_order" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "commerce_physical_rules_order_is_shippable" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ] } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_fees_apply" : {
      "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ],
      "fee" : "handling",
      "amount" : "5.50",
      "currency_code" : "USD",
      "include_tax" : "0"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that `5.50` is cents, and is rounded up to $0.06. You probably need to multiple your value by 100:

```
  "amount" : "550",
```

Comment: Ah, weird. I would have thought that 0.06 would be 6 cents. I'll try that. Sure enough, that fixed it. Sounds like some helper text saying it's in pennies or whatever would be good. I would have never thought to put 550 for $5.50.